# why I cann't add a new label to qwidget when I click a button

Tags: qt, qwidget, qlabel

I would like to add a new label to qwidget when I click a button, but it's doesn't working, but add a new label to qwidget in Constructor method is okay.

```
TestResult::TestResult(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    panel = new QWidget(this);
    panel->setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 220);
    panel->setStyleSheet("background: '#fafafa'");
    drawTest(); // this is working, but call drawTest in a click slot, it's not working.
}

void TestResult::drawTest() {
//    delete panel;
//    panel = new QWidget(this);
//    panel->setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 220);
//    panel->setStyleSheet("background: 'red'");
    row_i += 30;
    QLabel* label_title = new QLabel(panel);
    label_title->setText(tr("label %1").arg(row_i));
    label_title->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    label_title->setGeometry(0, row_i, 300, 20);
    qDebug() << label_title->text();

}
```

drawTest(); // this is working, but call drawTest in a click slot, it's not working.
I want call it in click slot

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] showing how you connect the signal and slot.

Comment: You probably forgot to call `show()` for the newly added widget(s).